How to call call function with parameters in gatsby Link-component
I am searching for the proper syntax for calling function with parameters and use return values of function as a state-parameter for a link.
Here you can see my code:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from "gatsby";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";

const TestParam = (props) => {
const data = [ {
    "RezeptId": 1,
    "RezeptTitel": "Rezept 1: Hamburger"
},
{
    "RezeptId": 2,
    "RezeptTitel": "Rezept 2: Wraps"
}];

const getRezept = (parameter_1, parameter_2) => {
    const abc = [{
        "id": 1,
        "text": "addition für 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "text": "addition für 2"
    }];
    // Do something
    // ...
    return abc[parameter_1];
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
         <h2>Rezepte</h2>
     <div>
        { data && data.map(rezept => {
             return(
              <div key={rezept.RezeptId}>
                   <Link to={`/ListRezept/${rezept.RezeptId}`} state={{ data: {_function_with_parameter(param1, param2)}}}>
                      <h1>{rezept.RezeptTitel.substring(0,25)}</h1>
                   </Link>
              </div>
             );
        })}
     </div>
     </Layout>
     );
        
     }

export default TestParam;

The "function_with_parameter()" value should be my call of function "get Rezepte" and I want to pass two paramters, which are 2 variable values.
Pseudocode of call function with parameter
state={{ data: {getRezept(${rezept.RezeptId}, ${rezept.RezeptTitel})}}}

Unfortunately it does not work :(
What is the proper syntax for calling "getRezepte" function with parameters and add the result of called function as a state-parameter in my Link?
For sure, the getRezept-function will have more logic inside later and also the "const data = [...]" value will be the result of a data fetch.
